# Using global state variables in coroutines?

Tags: python, global-variables, coroutine

I'm building a discord bot using the discord.py library - all user interaction therefore necessarily takes place in coroutines, defined with async and called with await.

One of my functions is going to require a saved state variable - a time offset used in a calculation that will occasionally need to be updated manually by users.

I can't use a normal global variable in the main thread - the coroutines can't see them.  What's a sensible design pattern for preserving a state variable between multiple coroutines?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u can work with a dict. For example:

```
x = {the name of the member:[stored variables]}
```

U can change the variable with:

```
x[variable u want to change] = variable u want to give it
```

[More about dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own thread safe class that wraps the state and use it like an in memory data store

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30624491)